# mysql query to join 3 queries in 1 table while averaging

Tags: mysql, join, average

I have 3 very large tables, with values getting logged every minute,
below is an *extract* of these tables.

I would like to get **hourly averages for a period of 1 Day** of these tables and join them with respect to time, please note there is a couple of seconds gap between log time for ph and temperature

***Table PH*** (extract only, this table is very large with more than 130,000 values)

```
    ID      time                Ph

    72176   2013-04-06 03:29:34 7.58
    72177   2013-04-06 03:30:34 7.58
    72178   2013-04-06 03:31:34 7.54
    72179   2013-04-06 03:32:34 7.58
    72180   2013-04-06 03:33:34 7.58
    72181   2013-04-06 03:34:34 7.58
    72182   2013-04-06 03:35:34 7.54
    72183   2013-04-06 03:36:34 7.58
    72184   2013-04-06 03:37:34 7.54
    72185   2013-04-06 03:38:34 7.58
    72186   2013-04-06 03:39:34 7.58
```

***Table temperature1*** (extract only, this table is very large with more than 130,000 values)

```
    ID      time            temperature

133312  2013-04-06 03:29:36 25.37
133313  2013-04-06 03:30:36 25.37
133314  2013-04-06 03:31:36 25.37
133315  2013-04-06 03:32:36 25.31
133316  2013-04-06 03:33:36 25.31
133317  2013-04-06 03:34:36 25.31
133318  2013-04-06 03:35:36 25.37
133319  2013-04-06 03:36:36 25.31
133320  2013-04-06 03:37:36 25.31
133321  2013-04-06 03:38:36 25.31
133322  2013-04-06 03:39:36 25.37
```

***Table solids*** (extract only, this table is very large with more than 130,000 values)

```
    ID      time            solids

123791  2013-04-06 03:29:49 140
123792  2013-04-06 03:30:49 140
123793  2013-04-06 03:31:49 143
123794  2013-04-06 03:32:49 140
123795  2013-04-06 03:33:49 140
123796  2013-04-06 03:34:49 140
123797  2013-04-06 03:35:49 140
123798  2013-04-06 03:36:49 143
123799  2013-04-06 03:37:49 140
123800  2013-04-06 03:38:49 140
123801  2013-04-06 03:39:49 140
```

I am currently getting hourly averages using the query below

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(x.time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
     , avg(x.solids) avg_solids
  FROM solids x where time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
 GROUP 
    BY DATE_FORMAT(x.time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00');
```

how can I efficiently join  (with respect to time)  the results of the query above for each sensor (x3) to be displayed in 1 table

===============================

this query below gets the hourly values, but not sure how to tweek it to get averages per hour

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timeTable.minuteTime, '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i') time,
(oT2.temperature) temperature,
(T2.temperature) temp,
(S2.solids) solids,
(P2.Ph) Ph


FROM
(
    SELECT minuteTime.minuteTime minuteTime,
    ( SELECT MAX(time) FROM outside_temperature WHERE time <= minuteTime.minuteTime AND time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) otempTime, 
    ( SELECT MAX(time) FROM temperature1 WHERE time <= minuteTime.minuteTime AND time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) tempTime, 
    ( SELECT MAX(time) FROM Ph WHERE time <= minuteTime.minuteTime AND time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) phTime,  
    ( SELECT MAX(time) FROM solids WHERE time <= minuteTime.minuteTime AND time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) solidsTime

    FROM  
    (
        SELECT DATE(time) + INTERVAL (HOUR(time) DIV 1 *1 ) HOUR minuteTime
        FROM Ph
        WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND time <= NOW()
        UNION SELECT DATE(time) + INTERVAL (HOUR(time) DIV 1 *1) HOUR
        FROM solids
        WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND time <= NOW()
        UNION SELECT DATE(time) + INTERVAL (HOUR(time) DIV 1 *1) HOUR
        FROM outside_temperature
        WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND time <= NOW()
        UNION SELECT DATE(time) + INTERVAL (HOUR(time) DIV 1 *1) HOUR
        FROM temperature1
        WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND time <= NOW()
        GROUP BY 1
    ) minuteTime
) timeTable
LEFT JOIN outside_temperature oT2 ON oT2.time = timeTable.otempTime
LEFT JOIN temperature1 T2 ON T2.time = timeTable.tempTime
LEFT JOIN solids S2 ON S2.time = timeTable.solidsTime
LEFT JOIN Ph P2 ON P2.time = timeTable.phTime


GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(timeTable.minuteTime, '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i') 
ORDER BY minuteTime ASC
```

Comment: there's no point in doing that date_format stuff for grouping. `GROUP BY DATE(x.time)` will accomplish the same thing, without forcing mysql to do a bunch of repetitive string formatting that'll be thrown away anyways.

Comment: do you need averages per hour or per day (or both)? or do you need averages per hour and then averages per day of averages per hour?

Comment: I need averages per hour only, but only limit display to 1 day worth of averages on a table

Comment: mark, group by date(x.time) does not get all ~24 results, i only get 2 results. this is probably due to the second delays between values!

Comment: Consider providing DDLs (or an SQLFIDDLE) together with the desired result set.

Answer (score 0):

[Hour()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) seems that it would be a useful function for this, since you are only looking at a single day. Perhaps something like this would work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT HOUR(time) hour, avg(ph) AS avg_ph
  FROM ph 
  WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  GROUP BY hour) p
JOIN 
 (SELECT HOUR(time) hour, avg(temperature) AS avg_temp
  FROM temperature1 
  WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  GROUP BY hour) t ON t.hour = p.hour
JOIN 
 (SELECT HOUR(time) hour, avg(solids) AS avg_solids
  FROM solids 
  WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  GROUP BY hour) s ON s.hour = p.hour;
```

Being that it is using inner joins, I'm making the assumption that there will always be at least one records in each table for the hour, but it seems like a reasonable assumption.

Comment: Thanks, your table works, but since i will be pushing the result table to a charting function, the time needs to show in the datetime format and furthermore the time on the queried table starts from 0 and finished at 23, if the current time is 5am for example I would like the query to pull i.e 5am yesterday to 5am today not 0am to 23pm. if you know what I mean.

Comment: I do, and it should be quite functional for 6am yesterday - 5am today.  Overlapping on 5am yesterday and 5am today would be a problem.  If it were me I would tweak the WHERE clause to deal only with whole hours.  If I were analyzing data and was presented with 23 sets of hourly stats, bookended by two half hours, I would definitely throw out the half hours.  As for the formatted time, just pull MIN(time) or something from any of the subqueries, and you're off to the races.

Comment: being a noob, would anyone be able to help, i am particularly interested in the formating of the time and its order

Comment: the query I just inserted above, gets the hourly values as required but i am not sure how to tweek it to do hourly averages

Comment: I did it, i simply inserted: SELECT  p.time,........ORDER BY p.time ASC. but now I was wondering how to get 2 days of data without overlapping. currently if I select 2 days, the query averages out the 2 days and display on 1 day