# Add an average column in array

Tags: r, statistics, dataframe, average

I was collecting local temperature on a hourly basis in a data.frame with 3 columns and many rows (1000+) in R:

Day -  Hour  - Temperature

- 1 - 11:00 - 14
- 1 - 12:00 - 17
- ...
- 2 - 11:00 - 10
- 2 - 12:00 - 19
- ...
- 3 - 11:00 - 15
- 3 - 12:00 - 9

I need to add a new column which contains average temperature within each hour interval.
In the example: average temperate at 11:00 equals 13ºC, at 12:00 equals 15C, so I need:

Day -  Hour  - Temperature - average

- 1 - 11:00 - 14 - 13
- 1 - 12:00 - 17 - 15
- ...
- 2 - 11:00 - 10 - 13
- 2 - 12:00 - 19 - 15
- ...
- 3 - 11:00 - 15 - 13
- 3 - 12:00 - 9 - 15

I tried cbind, aggregate but I failed. Any ideas?

Comment: When you say failed, what happened instead of what you were expecting?

Comment: Could you give us a sample of your data as a reproducible example ?

Comment: if you use `sqldf package` in `R`, solution for the similar question is mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839408/mysql-query-to-join-3-queries-in-1-table-while-averaging/15840578#15840578)

Comment: @user2261983 - Did the answer work out for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `df` is your data.frame, the following might work:

```
  avgTemp <- sapply(unique(df$Hour),function(x){mean(df$Temperature[df$Hour==x])})
  names(avgTemp) <- unique(df$Hour)

  df <- cbind(df,avgTemp[df$Hour])
```